# Making a flexible parameterized horn

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a model of horn acoustic:

[image: similar to this]

Actually, it should be a parameterized (for example, exponentally widening) tube, which can than be shaped/curved.
I've been trying Curve Modifier but it works OK only for one turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

You will need two objects.

1. Simple **Bezier Circle** which will **Bevel** your shape.
2. **Bezier Curved** shaped as needed with custom **Radius** values (per point) for **Beveling**.

[image: 1]

You can change **Radius** values by selecting point and changing it's value in **Transform tab** or by hitting <kbd>W</kbd> > **Set Curve Radius**.

[image: 2]

After that you can add **Solidify Modifier** and maybe <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > **Mesh from Curve**.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Luke! Didn't know about Radius changing.